# Why cant i change a instance?

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
public class Finance {
    private User user;

    private ArrayList<account> account;
    private ArrayList<Categorie> categorie;
    private ArrayList<salary> salary;

    private static final Finance instance=new GestaoFinancas();
    public static Finance getFinance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private Finance() {
        user=new User();
        account=new ArrayList<>();
        categorie=new ArrayList<>();
        salary=new ArrayList<>();

        categorie.add(new Categoria("Food"));
        categorie.add(new Categoria("Sleep"));
        categorie.add(new Categoria("Fun"));
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And im trying to add a new user to it:

```
import pt.finance.modelo.Finance;
...
User user = new User( jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText());
        getFinance().setUser(user);//here is the problem
```

My question is how can i give a new user, plus should i write Finance.getFinance or getFinance? Everytime i attempt to give Finance a new user i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.vista.DadosUtilizador.jButton2ActionPerformed(DadosUtilizador.java:127)
at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.vista.DadosUtilizador.access$200(DadosUtilizador.java:14)
at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.vista.DadosUtilizador$3.actionPerformed(DadosUtilizador.java:72)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.vista.FinancasPessoais.btnAlterarUtilizadorActionPerformed(FinancasPessoais.java:174)
at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.vista.FinancasPessoais.access$000(FinancasPessoais.java:13)
at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.vista.FinancasPessoais$1.actionPerformed(FinancasPessoais.java:51)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.modelo.Utilizador.<init>(Utilizador.java:21)
    at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.modelo.GestaoFinancas.<init>(GestaoFinancas.java:26)
    at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.modelo.GestaoFinancas.<clinit>(GestaoFinancas.java:20)
```

Comment: you should create an object of type GestaoFinancas and then add the user

Comment: Did you read the documentation for ExceptionInInitializerError? "Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer." You're getting an exception from instantiating that static var. The full trace should have the root cause.

Comment: Why do i need the instancia then? i could just pass the value from jframe to jframe as param. I was doing something similar until my prof said i should use getGestor

Comment: Post the full stacktrace please?

Comment: @Edwin - GestaoFinancas is a singleton, there's no need to create another one.  The problem is that the static instantiation is failing.  As yshavit says, the full stack trace will indicate the problem.

Comment: **please** do not write source-code in any other language than english. Its what every developer on the world agreed on - otherwise your code will be unmaintainable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  - Please **always** provide the *complete* error message including the *full* stack trace.

Comment: the name of the variable shouldnt count as other language, but ok, whit the information about what this is i think i can manage to solve the problem, thanks guy.

Comment: @GuyG that's a wannabe singleton

Comment: All of your classes, packages and even method names are in some other language than english - claiming that its just *"the name of the variable"* is ... worrying. The only english parts of your code probably are Java keywords. If you **ever** want to work for money or together with other people in a team you will most likely be forced to start writing in english. Just saying. Programming == english. Thats how it is.

Comment: All the code is written in english, if u will be willing to explain how why the problem is failing i would apreciate.

Comment: @JoãoMarques - As Timothy Truckle pointed out, you need to include the _full_ stack trace.  If you have posted all of the stack trace you can see, then you need to change your logging settings, because what you've posted is only a fraction of it.

Comment: hes blatantly stating the opposite of reality - which everyone can see ... now **that** is a serious problem right there. I think you may want to consider psychotherapy at some point ... just saying. Now focus on your spanish code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.modelo.Utilizador.<init>(Utilizador.java:21)
    at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.modelo.GestaoFinancas.<init>(GestaoFinancas.java:26)
    at pt.ipleiria.estg.es1.financaspessoais.modelo.GestaoFinancas.<clinit>(GestaoFinancas.java:20)
```

That's your problem.  On line 21 of your `Utilizador` class there's a problem (probably deliberately throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` to show that it hasn't been fully implemented yet).  So you're failing to instantiate `Utilizador`.  You should either look there and figure it out, or post that code too.

Comment: Thanks, it is my first time using a singleton.